# SQL Server query to non normalized table

Tags: sql-server

I have an unnormalized table of customer orders. I want count how many products are sold and display it in table by type.

```
OnlineSalesKey  SalesOrderNumber  ProductKey
--------------------------------------------
     1              20121018         778
     2              20121018         774
     3              20121018         665
     4              20121019         772
     5              20121019         778
     9              20121019         434
    10              20121019         956
    11              20121020         772
    12              20121020         965
    15              20121020         665
    16              20121020         778
    17              20121021         665
```

My query:

```
SELECT 
    s.ProductKey, COUNT (*) As Purchased 
FROM
    Sales s
GROUP BY 
    s.ProductKey
```

**Question #1.**

That query does a job. But now I want display and take into account only those orders where more than one item is purchased. Not sure how do i do that in one query.  Any ideas?

**Question #2**

Is it possible to normalize results and get back data separated by semi column?

```
20121018 | 778; 774; 665
```

Thanks!

Comment: What DBMS are you using (MySQL, SQL Server, etc.)?

Comment: Do you realize that for question 2 you want to actually denormalize your data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT s.ProductKey, COUNT (*) As Purchased 
FROM
Sales s
GROUP BY s.ProductKey
having count(*) > 1
```

**EDIT -**

Answer 1 - To display products for which orders had more than one product purchased -

```
SELECT s.ProductKey, COUNT (*) As Purchased 
FROM Sales s
WHERE SalesOrderNum in
(
select SalesOrderNum from Sales 
group by SalesOrderNum having count(*) > 1
)
GROUP BY s.ProductKey
```

Comment: This returns products that are sold more than once, not products from orders with more than one item

Answer (score 4):

You don't say which SQL database you're using, and there will be different, more-or-less efficient answers for each database. (Sorry, just noticed MSSQL is in the question title.)

Here's a solution that will work in all or most databases:

```
SELECT s.ProductKey, COUNT (*) As Purchased 
FROM Sales s
WHERE SalesOrderNum IN 
 (SELECT SalesOrderNum FROM Sales GROUP BY SalesOrderNum HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
GROUP BY s.ProductKey
```

This is not the *most* efficient, but should work across the most products.

Also, please note that you're using the terms normalized and unnormalized in reverse.  The table you have is normalized, the results you want are de-normalized.

There is no standard SQL statement to get the de-normalized results you want using SQL alone, but some databases (MySQL and SQLite) provide the group_concat function to do just this.

Answer (score 2):

### Q1: Look at [HAVING](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180199.aspx) clause

*display and take into account only those orders...*

```
SELECT s.SalesOrderNumber, COUNT (*) As Purchased 
FROM Sales s
GROUP BY s.SalesOrderNumber
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

So we group by the orders, apply the condition in HAVING, then display the SalesOrderNumber in the SELECT clause.

### Q2: Look at several group concatenation techniques.

MySQL:

```
SELECT s.SalesOrderNumber, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ProductKey
                                      ORDER BY ProductKey SEPARATOR '; ')
FROM Sales s
GROUP BY s.SalesOrderNumber
```

SQL Server: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1250533/573261) to a duplicate question.  Basically, using FOR XML.

Answer (score 1):

1) Try this one:

```
SELECT s.ProductKey, COUNT (*) As Purchased 
FROM
Sales s
GROUP BY s.ProductKey
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Comment: No, this will get the products purchase more than once, including orders with only a single product.